Can the function exists be used with a return value from the select?
what error in this code
if exists(select top 1 @entNum = entNum from View_Entry where typeID=@typeID and DocID= @entDayID)  
begin
    delete from [tbEntry] where [DocID]=@entDayID and [typeID]=@typeID
end
else
begin
    select @entNum =ISNULL(max(entNum)+1,1) from dbo.tbEntry
end

error Messages

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure tr_EntDay_tbEntry_INSERT_UPDate,
Line 19 Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 156, Level 15, State 1,
Procedure tr_EntDay_tbEntry_INSERT_UPDate, Line 23 Incorrect syntax
near the keyword 'else'.

I con not find error

Are you sure the error is in this code snippet ? You don't show us the complete code of the trigger here

I reproduced the error in a fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/0p_m9kAV

You can't use EXISTS this way. One alternative is: select top 1 @entNum = entNum from View_Entry where typeID=@typeID and DocID= @entDayID IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 BEGIN <your code>... 

Looks like you are trying to reimplement a SEQUENCE manually for some reason.

A query that assigns value to variable, does not yield any result set, which is required for EXISTS operator:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

